# losing value of variable that pass from AS3 to asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, actionscript-3

I want to pass value of Name.Text From AS3 to Asp.net.But after passing , Content of Request.Form["Name"] Can not be saved in label1.text. Can someone help me.

**Actionscript 3.0 Code :**

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    var scRequest: URLRequest = new URLRequest("MyPage.aspx");
    var scLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    scLoader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    var scVars: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    scVars.Name = Name.text;
    scRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    scRequest.data = scVars;
    scLoader.load(scRequest);
    Name.text = "";
}
```

**CSharp Code :**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      if (Request.Form["Name"] != null)
             Label1.Text = Request.Form["Name"];
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you not looking for `Request.Form["FirstName"]` instead?

Comment: No Request.Form["Name"]

Comment: Your ActionScript 3 code looks fine. Try to use an absolute URL ( like http://example.com/script.aspx ), and to verify your .NET code ...

Comment: I did it but it was not correct.